# Ruby regex that removes everything except name; example gem_name (abcd-123)

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm doing a little script that installs all the gems, and I did that, but I have a question regarding this;

a file containing list of gems looks like this:
 adapter (0.5.2)
 do_sqlite3 (0.10.8 x86-mingw32)

and many others. If I readline from script I could do foo.gsub /[^a-zA-Z]/,'' to remove numbers. But then it removes numbers from gem name and I have letters inside parentheses left. So I would like a regex that removes everything except gem name. Any help or link will do.

Tnx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, my first question would be about your goal for installing a list of gems.  There might already be a tool out there that solves your underlying problem.  ([bundler](http://gembundler.com/)?)

A regex that might work, though, would be to remove the portions of the string enclosed by parenthesis:  `/\([^\)]*\)/`

```
> "adapter (0.5.2) do_sqlite3 (0.10.8 x86-mingw32)".gsub /\([^\)]*\)/, ''
=> "adapter  do_sqlite3 "
```

Comment: I'm just messing around, but I need to install all the gems again, so I thought about a quicker way.